# Mapping two tables with different primary keys to one entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm making an application using EF on a legacy database. In the database there are two tables I am concerned with. The structure (in C# form) looks like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int employeeID {get; set;} //primary key
    public string name {get; set;}
    ...//other attributes from this table (not relevant)
}
public class EmployeeProfile
{
    public int profileID {get; set;} //primary key
    public int employeeID {get; set;}
    public string favoritemovie {get; set;}
    ...//other attributes from this table (not relevant)
}
```

There is a 1 - 1 relationship with `EmployeeProfile` and `Employee` in the database. In my application, I'm wanting to create a combined entity, like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int employeeID {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}              //taken from Employee Table
    public string favoritemovie { get; set; }   //taken from EmployeeProfile table
}
```

How can I do this? I've heard of entity splitting but that requires the tables to have the same primary key.

Answer (score 0):

EF already creates the relationships for you. You should be able to access EmployeeFile via the Employee entity (i.e. employee.EmployeeProfile[0] grabs the employee profile related to the employee enitty you retrieved)

Answer (score 0):

As RandomAsianGuy stated, it's trivial to jump to the profile entity from the employee entity.

If you insist on creating this merged entity, however, what you're looking for is table-per-type (TPT) mapping inheritance in Entity Framework, using Employee as the base class and deriving EmployeeProfile from Employee.

Here is an MSDN walk-through of TPT inheritance using EDMX:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293